# Background Color and Tags

Tags: html, background, background-color

I have a simple question for you that I am not sure about. If a p tag has no CSS-code but the body tag has following code:

```
 body {
 background-color: white;
 color: red;
 font-family: "Calibri";
}
```

... I know that the p tag gets the color red and the font Calibri, but does the p tag get the background color

```
background-color: white
```

...or does it get no background-color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `<p>` tag  gets the `background-color`, if no `background-color` is set for the `<p>` tag.

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<p>test text</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
background-color: red;
font-family: "Calibri";
}
```

Now you have `background-color: red;` and no other `background-color` is set for the `<p>` tag so the `<p>` tag gets `background-color: red;`.

[image]

But if you set a `background-color` to the `<p>` tag, the `background-color` of the `<p>` tag is preferred.

**HTML:**

```
<p style="background-color: green;">test text</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
background-color: red;
font-family: "Calibri";
}
```

So the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank u. Now I understand!